# Gradle copy build script dependency to folder

Tags: gradle

We are building one of our applications with gradle and part of the distribution I want to include an external jar which is not a run time dependency in a config folder. That jar is needed as part of the application install and it contains some custom ant tasks.

Our build script dependency looks like below:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'my-group:custom-tasks:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

How would I access and copy the `custom-task-1.2.3.jar` into a certain folder so I can include it in my distribution? Something like below:

```
task copyCustomTasks {
    doLast {
        copy {
            // This below is a make up to express what I want
            from buildscript.dependencies
            include 'custom-tasks*.jar'
            into "$buildDir/config"
        }
    }
}
```

If this is not the gradle way of doing things please let me know what alternatives I have.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**
I solved my problem in a different way by creating an extra configuration. However I would still be interested to find out how you can access build script dependencies at run time. Thanks again for your inputs.

```
configurations {
    install {
        description = "application install classpath"
        transitive = true
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    install('my-group:custom-tasks:1.2.3')
    ...
}
...
task copyInstallDeps {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from configurations.install
            into "$buildDir/config"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quite close:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
   }
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
   from buildscript.configurations.classpath
   into 'lib'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Opal. It looks like I am missing some basic strategy to look into the gradle API. When you see buildscript has a dependencies entry you would assume that is how you should point to it. What would be an easy way to remeber/realize that `buildscript.configurations.classpath` should be used instead of `buidscript.dependencies.classpath`? Is it just me or the API is a bit inconsistent. Anyway thank you for the valid answer.